# Cordova iOS: "ERROR: Start Page at `www/index.html` was not found"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I had to setup a xCode project with Cordova. Never worked with Cordova before. And got this error when starting the simulator.

NVM 14.20
NPM 6.14.17
Corodva 11.0
xCode 13.4.1

I installed with `sudo npm install -g cordova`
Installed the sim `sudo npm install -g ios-sim`
Generated the project `cordova platform add ios`

The www folder in the project is empty, where should it come from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create your cordova project

```
 sudo npm install -g cordova
 cordova create DIR_NAME PACKAGE_NAME
 cordova platform add ios
```